# Discontinuity of $f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2 &\text{ if } x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ 5-x^2 &\text{ if } x \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Consider a function $f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2 &\text{ if } x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ 5-x^2 &\text{ if } x \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$ defined on the interval $(0,1)$.

I think this function is nowhere continuous. A similar function that I discovered is the [Dirichlet function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_function) and the proof there seems to apply here. But I don't understand the proof. Is there a way this can be proven by showing that the left-hand and the right-hand limits are different?

Edit: Someone pointed out in the comments that $f$ is continuous at $x = \pm \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$. If you're writing an answer, if possible, please explain the continuity and discontinuity at each point in $\mathbb{R}$ (rather than just $(0,1)$). That will be more helpful.

Comment: It is continuous at $\pm \sqrt 5 /2$

Comment: @geetha290krm $\sqrt{5}/2 \simeq 1.118$ is not in $(0,1)$

Comment: I was looking at the title. The question  does not agree with the title.  @Didier

Comment: @geetha290krm You're right!

Comment: @geetha290krm That's because there's limited space, but the fact that you mentioned it was very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way this can be proven by showing that the left-hand and the right-hand limits are different?

**No.**

The term (for example) *left-hand* limit, in the context of this problem, refers to the limit as $x$ approaches $a$ **from below**, for a particular $(a)$ in the range $0 < a < 1.$

The phrase *approaches from below* means that you are confining your focus to those values of $x$ that are getting closer and closer to the value $a$, but where each of the values of $x$ under consideration is strictly less than $a$.

---

That type of consideration does not represent **why** the function is discontinuous throughout the interval $0 < a < 1.$  Instead, the reason is that in the Real number system, both rational and irrational numbers are *dense*.

I will illustrate with a specific example.

Suppose that $a = (1/2).$  Suppose that you take any (**small**) $\delta > 0.$  Rather than examine the neighborhood $-\delta < (x-a) < \delta, ~: ~x \neq a,$

examine the two **sub-neighborhoods**,

- $-\delta < x < a ~: ~$ Neighborhood-1
- $a < x < \delta ~: ~$ Neighborhood-2

Regardless of how small (positive) $\delta$ is taken, Neighborhood-1 will contain both a rational and an irrational number.  The same is true for Neighborhood-2.

So, attempting to focus on the left-side and right-side limits will not help.  Instead, you must confront exactly what it means for the rational and irrational numbers to both be *dense in* $\Bbb{R}.$

As to the points of continuity outside the range of $0 < a < 1$, the function will be continuous at a given point $(a)$, if and only if $a^2 = 5 - a^2.$

The reason for this is that in any Neighborhood around any value of $(a)$, of radius $\delta$, there will be values of $x$ that will be

- arbitrarily close to $a$ and rational
- arbitrarily close to $a$ and irrational.

Therefore, the continuity at $a$ will exist if and only if the values of the function for rational elements in the $\delta$ neighborhood  and irrational elements in the $\delta$ neighborhood are both **approaching the same value**.

This will be true if and only if $(5-a^2) = a^2.$